# Microsoft Office Web Apps for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

This might be a silly question. I was planning to install the latest security update for MS Office web apps. We have a SP 2010 farm. My question is what is the difference between "Security Update for Microsoft Web Applications" and "Security Update for Microsoft Web Applications - Farm Deployment"? Is it stand alone against Farm with web and app servers?I have a farm where I installed the first option. What do I do now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which patch do you want to install? Where do you see those two different updates?

Comment: So, I basically installed wac2010-kb4011709-fullfile-x64-glb. If you see this link https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4011709 it has two patches , one that says farm deployment and one normal. This is a security update for Office web apps. Our environment is a 2 apps and 3 webs. I installed the normal one on all servers and I am not sure whether I did it right. I ran the config wizard and everything looks ok though

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this difference before. [Looks like Microsoft always puts two Update-Links to the UpdateCatalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Security%20Update%20for%20Microsoft%20Web%20Applications). The linked file is exactly the same. I downloaded some and compared their Hashes - identical.

From your description in the comments, you did exactly the right steps.